# Accurate behavior of the sort method in C#?

Tags: c#, sorting

```
    static void Main()
    {
        var array = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        Array.Sort(array, (x, y) => x % 2 == y % 2 ? 0 : x % 2 == 1 ? -1 : 1);
        array.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }
```

`The output result is 3,5,1,2,4.`

According to my understanding, in the sort delegate: Odd numbers equal odd numbers; Even number equal even numbers; Odd numbers are before even numbers. Why the output is not 1,3,5,2,4? Thanks.

Comment: because you didnt tell it you wanted it sorted ascending numerically.  if you don't specify a behavior, then the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Indeed - you said it yourself, "odd numbers equal odd numbers" - so 1, 3 and 5 are all equal. `Array.Sort` is not a stable sort, so equal numbers can come out in any order.

Comment: You'd be better off using LINQ `GroupBy` to do this.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky, it is not "as expected" but rather "happen to be" - even in 4.0 [Array.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxt053xf(v=vs.100).aspx) is not guaranteed to keep order - "...This implementation performs an unstable sort" as mentioned above by Jon (which should be an asnwer...)

Comment: Just interesting - why in .net 4.0 I have different output for these array elements?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I've tested and got the same results as OP for .NET 3.5 to 4.5 on Windows 7 x64 ([and with mono 2.8](http://ideone.com/XqRRK1)). Anyway, even documentation says that `Array.Sort` does not guarantee any order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf1f0bc.aspx):

> Array.Sort uses the QuickSort algorithm. This implementation performs an unstable sort; that is, if two elements are equal, their order might not be preserved. In contrast, a stable sort preserves the order of elements that are equal.

Comment: Note that Linq's OrderBy *is* documented to be a stable sort.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense for quick sort. Use 1 as the pivot, according to the rules, 2 and 4 should be put into the right-side-element list. 3 and 5 are put into the left-side-element list, 1 takes the 3rd position. For the left-side-element and right-side-element list, the order doesn't need to be changed. Thus the result is 3,5,1,2,4.

Comment: well, the understanding doesn't work well with the original array changed to 1,2,3,4,5,6. The actual output is 3,5,1,6,2,4. Anyway, the order of equal elements is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

You are just comparing even and odd in your comparer function. Like the others said, quicksort is non-stable. Why not add an additional check for value in addition to even/odd when the values are both either even or odd.

```
// if x odd and y even return -1
// else if x even and y odd return 1
// else return x.CompareTo(y)

Array.Sort(array, (x, y) => x % 2 == y % 2 ? x.CompareTo(y) : x % 2 > y % 2 ? -1 : 1);
```